# *args in recursion: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, recursion, args

I am learning python. trying to use take *args as parameter in a recursion function (for addition of 'n' numbers), but getting error: Below is my code and error:

---

```
def add(*n):
  if len(n) == 1:
    return n[0]
  else:
    sum =  n[len(n)-1] + add(n[:-1])
  return sum  


a = add(2,4,6)
print(a)
```

---

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/9d1de49c52e0e9b9/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    a = add(2,4,6)
  File "/tmp/sessions/9d1de49c52e0e9b9/main.py", line 18, in add
    sum =  n[len(n)-1] + add(n[:-1])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

please explain what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose a simpler setup:

```
def add(*n):
    if len(n) == 1:
        return n[0]
    return n[0] + add(*n[1:])    # n[1:] gives the "rest" of a list, i.e. all elements after the first.
```

- In a function **definition** (`def add(*n):`), the star collects multiple separate arguments into a list.
  e.g. when you call `add(2, 4, 6)`, then `n` will be a list `[2, 4, 6]`
- In a function **call** (`add(*n)`) the star spreads a list into multiple separate arguments.
  e.g. when you have `n = [2, 4, 6]`, then calling `add(*n)` will be as if you had called `add(2, 4, 6)`

In order to a list that to a function that collects its arguments, you need to spread it out first.

Your code did the first thing, but not the second. That's why it doesn't work:

```
def add(*n):                            # <-- collecting multiple arguments into a list
  if len(n) == 1:
    return n[0]
  else:
    sum =  n[len(n)-1] + add(n[:-1])    # <-- not spreading list into multiple arguments
  return sum
```

---

FWIW, an even shorter implementation would go like this

```
def add(*n):
    return 0 if not n else n[0] + add(*n[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

`n[:-1]` is returning a tuple, to get the last value into add use `add(n[-1])`
Edit:
working solution:

```py
def add(*n):
    if len(n) == 1:
        return n[0]
    else:
        return n[-1] + add(*n[:-1])
```

Comment: Thanks Tamir. it does fix the error. however now it gives incorrect/wrong answers. I passed arguments add(2,4,6,3, 5) to get 10 as their sum